# Check in R if reactive dataframe exists in if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, reactive

I am making a dashboard using R Shiny that has an overview page with a number of charts. All charts are created using the same module.
Users can select one subject they want all charts to show, but not all subjects exist for all charts.

Therefore, with certain selections not all charts will show data.
In those cases I would like to show a text that tells the user that the subject is not available for that specific chart.

The input for my chart is a dataframe that is only created if the subject exists:

```
  data_indicator <- reactive({
   req(input$choice %in% data$subject)
    data_indicator <- data %>%
      filter(subject ==  input$choice)
  })
```

I have made two outputs:
one that creates a chart ("plot"), and one that shows a text ("text").

Now I want to check if the dataframe has been created to choose which one to use. I've tried doing this using the following statement:

```
  output$plot_text <- renderUI({
    if (exists("data_indicator()")){
      output <- highchartOutput(ns("plot"))
     } else {
      output <- div(htmlOutput(ns("text")))
    }
    tagList(output)
  })
```

But it doesn't work, all charts now show the text, even the ones that should be available.

Does the exists command not work with a reactive dataset? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: Try changing to `exists("data_indicator")`

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. Since my dataframe is reactive I think I have to add the ().

Answer (score 1):

If you filter too much of your data, for example, if you filter a variable on a value it does not contain, the data.frame will still exist, it just will have zero rows. Therefore you need to check whether it has zero rows, and if that is the case, you might want to display a proper error or warning message.

**Update:**

The OP points out that the above does not apply to his reactive data frame, since he uses `req()` which stops the creation of the data frame in the first place.

In this case it is advisable to use `validate/need` instead of `req()`.

> Since **req causes outputs to stop silently**, it’s not useful in
>   situations where the user needs to be told what values are missing or
>   what user actions need to be taken to proceed.
>   
> **In that case, you need
>   the more flexible validation Feature**, which provides a superset of
>   req’s features via the validate/need functions; req(x) is mostly just
>   shorthand for validate(need(x, message = FALSE)).

Taken from [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html).

Below I provide a simple example using the iris data set.

I also recommend this [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) from RStudio on `validate()` and need functions.

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")


shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage(

        # Layout with sidebar
        sidebarLayout(

            ## Sidebar -----
            sidebarPanel(

                # > some example input on sidebar -----

                selectInput("choice", "Choose species",
                            choices = c("none",
                                        unique(as.character(iris$Species))),
                            selected = "setosa")

            ), # closes Sidebar-Panel



            # Main-Panel ------
            mainPanel(
                br(),
                tabsetPanel(

                    # > Plot -------

                    tabPanel("Plot tab",
                             value = 1,

                             plotOutput("plot_text")

                    ), # closes tabPanel

                    id = "tabselected", type = "pills"

                )  # closes tabsetPanel      

            )  # closes mainPanel                      

        ) # closes sidebarLayout

    ), # closes fluidPage


    # Server ------
    server = function(input, output, session){

        data_indicator <- reactive({

            validate(
                need(input$choice %in% iris$Species, "No plot available for chosen filter criteria!")
            )

            iris %>%
                mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>%
                filter(Species == input$choice)

        })

        output$plot_text <- renderPlot({


            # Alternativly use validate here in the following way:
            # validate(
            #     need(input$choice %in% data_indicator()$Species, "No plot available for chosen filter criteria!")
            # )

            ggplot(data_indicator(), aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
                geom_col()


        })

    } # Closes server
) # Closes ShinyApp
```

Comment: Thank you for you elaborate answer! In my case the dateframe does not have zero rows, it really does not exist due to the req(). And the mixing of plot and text output does work, I use this in other module's and it works just fine. I'm not sure if the validate() option will work; I don't know how to provide it with the proper condition, since exists("data_indicator()") does not work, which was my issue to start with. ;) (I do agree that using validate() would be a nicer solution to my if statement!)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I did not take into account that you use `req()`. In your case it seems advisable to use `validate()` *instead* of `req()`. See my updated answer.